# CSS Crop/Cross marks

Tags: css

I'm in the process at looking to create print ready PDF documents using PHP.

My first problem is, that I'd like to see what the document looks like in HTML beforehand, this is fine, but I need to add crop/cross marks to the HTML.

I've seen the CSS `cross and crop` attributes, but I do't see them in my HTML when viewing in the browser:

I've added  `@page {sheet-size:A4; marks:crop cross; size:207mm 297mm; margin:0;}`

This doesn't show the crop marks.

Could someone point me in the right direction or provide a quick example where they show?

thanks

Comment: `marks` does not exist in CSS2.1; it was removed as part of the changes made to CSS2.0. It does exist in the [GCPM module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#marks), but I'm not sure about implementations.

Comment: But they are available in CSS3

Comment: So why did you tag your question [css2.1]?

Comment: I wasn't sure If they were part of the CSS2.1 spec as well